# Submit form in ViewPager

Tags: android, json, forms, android-viewpager

I have a From designed in **ViewPager** with 5 fragments which consists of all type of inputs(radio group, text, date, drop down) in it. I have to save and submit the form data on submit button click on last fragment.
Now I want to how to keep data saved while traversing between pages of view pager and send a **post request** at end of view pager? because in view pager i can store state of only 3 pages, while when I traverse to 4th page I will loose data of 1st page. Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: You can store data at application level. Take a look [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Understanding-the-Android-Application-Class)

Comment: Little trick is set this tag to view pager `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5)` when u traverse to other pages the all fragments stats remain.

Answer (score 0):

I think for your problem the best solution is to create a singleton that contains your object
and at each transition from one fragment to another you update the object in the singleton

Answer (score 0):

Singleton class is the answer for answer. [Singleton](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singleton-class-java/) - Only one instance of the class at a time.

Example :

Your singleton will be like this,

```
public class AddProductSingleton {

private static AddProductSingleton instance = null;
private String Category;
private String Title;
private String SubTitle;
private String Description;


private AddProductSingleton(){ }

public static AddProductSingleton getInstance(){
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new AddProductSingleton();

    return instance;
}


public String getCategory() {
    return Category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    Category = category;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return Title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    Title = title;
}

public String getSubTitle() {
    return SubTitle;
}

public void setSubTitle(String subTitle) {
    SubTitle = subTitle;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return Description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    Description = description;
}
```

And your fragments will be this,
First Fragment

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    AddProductSingleton objAddProductDetails = AddProductSingleton.getInstance();
    objAddProductDetails.setCategory("Fragment1")
}
```

Second Fragment,

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
     ddProductSingleton objAddProductDetails = AddProductSingleton.getInstance();
     objAddProductDetails.setTitle("Fragment2")
}
```

Third Fragment,

```
public class Fragment3 extends Fragment {
     ddProductSingleton objAddProductDetails = AddProductSingleton.getInstance();
     objAddProductDetails.setSubTitle("Fragment3")
}
```

Fourth Fragment,

```
public class Fragment4 extends Fragment {
     ddProductSingleton objAddProductDetails = AddProductSingleton.getInstance();
     objAddProductDetails.setDescription("Fragment4")
}
```

After this your singleton object posses all the values sets in different fragments.

```
objAddProductDetails.getCategory() // Fragment1
objAddProductDetails.getTitle() // Fragment2
objAddProductDetails.getSubTitle() // Fragment3
objAddProductDetails.getDescription() // Fragment4
```

I hope this will be best proper solution to your query, Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I solved it using ViewModel with LiveData

Comment: Okay @PragathiRani You can add answer in this post. it will be helpful to others.